# Eloquent API Resources - Adding asset link to nested value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-api

I am trying to add an asset link to a nested `properties` value using Eloquents API resource function:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
     'id' => $this->id,
     'title' => $this->title,
     'image' => isset($this->image) ? asset('storage/'.$this->image) : null,
     'properties' => $this->properties,
     'created_at' => (string) $this->created_at,
     'updated_at' => (string) $this->updated_at
   ];
}
```

The following works fine for the `image` value, but I am using a nested `properties['pdf']` file that I need to add `asset('storage/')` parameter to so it outputs the full URL.

How am I able to pass `isset($this->properties['pdf']) ? asset('storage/'.$this->properties['pdf']) : null` into the properties value? I still need the `pdf` value to return inside the properties value.

Note: There are other values inside `properties` but they are dynamic based on the data returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the cleanest idea but this worked:

```
    $properties = $this->properties;
    if(isset($this->properties['pdf']) && $this->properties['pdf'] != null){
      $properties['pdf'] = asset('storage/'.$this->properties['pdf']);
    }
```

Then I applied `$properties` to the return.